# PostgreSQL : finding all lines intersecting with a polygon

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I am totally new in the world of GIS but as a student surveyor I am working on a project using postgreSQL and PostGIS.

I have one database with all the roads of my country (lines), and one database with a lot of area's (polygons). And for every polygon, I need to find all the roads (lines) that intersect with it (contain in partially or fully).

I do know the ST_Intersects function, but is this the best function to use ? right now I am trying to make a loop function where I loop all the roads to see if they intersect, but there must be a quicker way..

If anybody could get me started, that would be great!

Thanks

Comment: Do you really mean two *databases* or do you mean two *tables* in a single database? There generally isn't ever any quick way to do a "find every for each" query.

Comment: I mean 2 tables, sorry

Comment: Do you use OSM data? In my case I had to transform the OSM data geometries to the same projection like my other geometries are stored in the database.

Answer (score 2):

Leave the looping for the database. This is SQL.

```
SELECT polygons.id, lines.id 
FROM polygons, lines 
WHERE ST_Intersects(lines.geom,polygons.geom);
```

Put spatial indexes on the geometry columns.

Comment: I did put spatial indexes on both my tables (USING gist(..) ), and then did this query;

SELECT wvb_gid, wbn_gid 
FROM wvb, wbn 
WHERE ST_Intersects(wvb_geom,wbn_geom);

But I always get this error;

*ERROR:  invalid join selectivity: 187087368.000000
********** Error **********
ERROR: invalid join selectivity: 187087368.000000
SQL state: XX000*

I am google'ing it but I have no idea what this means

Comment: @user28088: Your problem is discussed in this link: http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/2543. Could be helpful.